# Set values (and text) of items of asp.net Radio Button List using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to set values (and text) of items of asp.net Radio Button List Using JQuery. I am trying to select index of RBL items and set their value and text. I have tried various variants without success. Any help please. Following is my markup.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBL" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
</form>
```

```
<head runat="server">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $($('#RBL').get[1]).val('One');
    $($('#RBL').index(2)).val('Two');
    $($('#RBL')[3]).val('Value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go this way:

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var values = ["One","Two","three", "four"];

    $("#RBL").children().find("input:radio").each(function (i, e) {
        e.value = values[i];
        e.innerHTML = values[i];
        i++;
    });

});
```

Create an array with the values you want and pass them into your radios.